# VB.NET equivalent of Func

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a C# statement

```
solidGauge1.LabelFormatter = val => val.ToString("P");
```

I want the VB.NET equivalent. Telerik code converter gives

```
"solidGauge1.LabelFormatter = Function(val) val.ToString("P")"
```

This is not correct since it seems to be ignored. The C# statment works in a C# project. The usage/source of this is [lvCharts Gauge control](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/180%20Gauge)

Comment: The conversion is correct apart from the quotes (`""`) around the whole line (don't know if you accidentally added these yourself or if the converter did).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
solidGauge1.LabelFormatter = Val.ToString("P")
```

Comment: That's an assignment of `val`, which probably is the [`Func<T, TResult>` delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)'s argument. So your code will not compile, IMO. [See the source code](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/blob/0d5f7f56d0dc9067f3ece48e293064e9ac1ac5a8/WinFormsView/Gauge.cs#L128).